# post method in not working rest api in magento

Tags: php, rest, magento-1.7

i use this code

```
$headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => '*/*');
$oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, $productData, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST, $headers);
$response =  json_decode($oauthClient->getLastResponseInfo());
```

but get

```
{"messages":{"error":[{"code":403,"message":"Access denied"}
```

somebody please help me how to add a simple product in magento site with the help of REST api post method.

Comment: are you sure you're $oauthClient is right?
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/authentication/oauth_configuration.html

Comment: $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
it returns me bool(true)